# Função em R não está pegando o parâmetro corretamente

Tags: r, funções, programação-funcional

Estou criando uma função, porém na hora de chamar a função, o parâmetro não está funcionando ao realizar o FILTER e o SUM.

Para selecionar a coluna ou para realizar uma contagem do tipo n(), funciona corretamente.

Segue exemplo:

```
df <- data.frame(C1 = c(1,2,NA,3))

df_funcao = function(PERIODO){
  soma = df %>% 
  dplyr::select(PERIODO) %>%
  filter(PERIODO != 'NA') %>% 
  summarise(soma = sum(PERIODO))

return(soma)
  
}

df_2 <- df_funcao(C1)
df_2
```

Aqui da um erro tipo character, porém está como formato numerico.

> Error: Problem with `summarise()` column `soma`.
> i `soma = sum(PERIODO)`.
> x invalid 'type' (character) of argument
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A maneira atual avalia a variável com `{{.}}`.

```
packageVersion("dplyr")
#[1] ‘1.0.7’

df_funcao = function(PERIODO){
  df %>% 
    dplyr::select({{PERIODO}}) %>%
    filter(!is.na({{PERIODO}})) %>% 
    summarise(soma = sum({{PERIODO}}))
}

df_2 <- df_funcao(C1)
df_2
#  soma
#1    6
```

A maneira anterior (a partir de `dplyr` versão `0.6.0`) era transformar a variável `PERIODO` numa `quosure` antes de a avaliar.

```
df_funcao <- function(PERIODO){
  PERIODO <- enquo(PERIODO)
  df %>% 
    dplyr::select(!!PERIODO) %>%
    filter(!is.na(!!PERIODO)) %>% 
    summarise(soma = sum(!!PERIODO))
}

df_2 <- df_funcao(C1)
df_2
#  soma
#1    6
```

---

### Edição

A função `df_funcao` acima só tem um argumento e utiliza `df` que está no `.GlobalEnv` porque é assim que está na pergunta.

A melhor maneira é as funções só utilizarem os argumentos que lhes são passados. Em `tidyverse` isso significa que para poder ser usada num *pipe*, o primeiro argumento deve ser o conjunto de dados, o `data.frame`.

A função revista fica então como se segue.

```
df_funcao2 <- function(x, PERIODO){
  x %>% 
    dplyr::select({{PERIODO}}) %>%
    filter(!is.na({{PERIODO}})) %>% 
    summarise(soma = sum({{PERIODO}}))
}

df_funcao2(df, C1)
df %>% df_funcao2(C1)
```

Comment: Deu certo, não tinha encontrado em nenhum outro lugar está forma.